# TruffleContract At() function with Drizzle

Tags: truffle, dapps, truffle-contract, drizzle

I am learning the Drizzle framework after I did a project using TruffleContract abstractions in Javascript (DApp).

I have multiple instances of a contract and I am not able to access at the instances "older" than the last deployed one. With TruffleContract I have the `at(address)` function that (slowly) retrieves the contract with address `address`.

For example:

I deploy 3 contracts "MyContract" c1, c2, c3, each one with a different storage variables. Then with TruffleContract I can call these functions:

```
const getContract = require('truffle-contract')
const contractJSON = require('./MyContract.json')

const contract = getContract(contractJSON)
contract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider)

const instance_c3 = await contract.deployed() // returns the last deployed, c3
const instance_c2 = await contract.at(address_c2) // retrieve c2
```

How does it work with Drizzle?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following way:

Get contract JSON data:

```
const contract_artifacts = require('../../../build/contracts/contract.json');
```

Create Truffle Contract object:

```
const truffleContract = await this.web3Service.artifactsToContract(contract_artifacts);
```

Get the contract deployed to a specific address:

```
const contractInstance = await truffleContract.at(CONTRACTADDRESS);
```

Fill contract name (you can modify the function to pass it as a third parameter):

```
contractInstance.contractName = truffleContract.contractName;


  await this.drizzleService.addContract(contractInstance, EventsArray);
```

Bellow is the dynamic addition of the smart contract to Drizzle:

```
  async addContract(truffleContract: any, events: string[]) {

    if(!truffleContract.contractName) {
      throw new Error('When Calling Drizzle.addContract(...), TruffleContract.contractName is not defined.');
    }
    var contractConfig = {
      contractName: truffleContract.contractName, 
      web3Contract: truffleContract.contract
    }

    // Add using the Drizzle context object
    this.drizzle.addContract(contractConfig, events)
  }
```